# Docker: I can't map ports other than 80 to my WordPress container

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, containers, port

I want to map some random port on my computer e.g. `localhost:7006` to my WordPress docker container's `port 80`.When I change the port of WordPress from `80:80` to `7006:80` it's not only stops working on `localhost(port 80)` but also don't respond on `localhost:7006`.

`docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
        version: '3'
    services:
      wordpress:
        depends_on:
          - db
        image: wordpress:4.7.1
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content 
        environment:
          WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
          WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd!
        ports:
          - 80:80 # Expose http and https
          - 8443:443
        networks:
          - wp_nwk
      db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: always
        volumes:
           - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd!
        networks:
          - wp_nwk
      phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
          - db
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 7005:80
        environment:
          PMA_HOST: db
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd!
        networks:
          - wp_nwk
    networks:
      wp_nwk:
    volumes:
      db_data:
```

Comment: Have you made sure, that there is nothing else running on port 7006? You could check that with the command `sudo netstat -tulpn`

Comment: Yes there is nothing running on the port before I run docker-compose up.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After a bit of research I found out that the WordPress container sets it's ports once since it needs to save the URLs(`localhost:7006`) in the db because I am persisting the db data.

I ran the `docker-compose up` once with the default port `80:80` configuration which caused the `localhost:80` or `localhost` to be saved in the db. So when I changed the ports again and ran `docker-compose up`, I actually messed up the URLs that are stored in the linked mysql db container with my WordPress container.

I ran `docker-compose down --volumes` (this causes the persisted data destruction)
and then changed the ports of my WordPress container in docker-compse.yml. Running the following command again created my WordPress container live on port 7006 (`localhost:7006`).
`docker-compose up`

```
wordpress:
depends_on:
  - db
image: wordpress:4.7.1
restart: always
volumes:
  - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content 
environment:
  WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
  WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd!
ports:
  - 7006:80 # Expose http and https
  - 8443:443
networks:
  - wp_nwk
```

> IMPORTANT: I am just playing with docker, so I don't want to save my
>   volumes data. Anyone wanting to keep their data must not use the
>   `docker-compose down --volumes`

It's running on the desired port now
[image]

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to change the port number in the db? I need to persist the volume data.

Comment: You would have to edit your database manually using phpmyadmin.

Comment: Yeah, I update value of siteurl, home in wp_options table and it working.

Answer (score 5):

I|f you want to change the port, you need to do the follow step. I successfully changed my WordPress port

1. run WordPress with default **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

2. login wordpress and change site url and home in setting to you want
3. use follow command in wordpress container

```
docker exec -it *wordpres_container_id* bash
```

4. add the follow line to `wp_config.php`

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

5. change `docker-compose.yml` ports to 80
6. restart container use follow command

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to change the [WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)] from wordpress admin, and then change the port in docker-compose without destroying the data in the volume.